# Splice altering my initial array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, splice

I am looking to remove the first two elements of an array and use both the new array and the model later in my code. My issue is that splice() is even altering my arrayModel in my code.

Here is my code

```
var arrayModel = ['a','b','c','d']

function dontAlterMyModel (arrayModel) {
  arrayTemp = arrayModel
  arrayTemp.splice(0, 2)
  console.log("arrayModel", arrayModel)
  console.log("arrayTemp", arrayTemp)
  return
}

dontAlterMyModel(arrayModel)
```

Here is the result:

```
arrayModel [ 'c', 'd' ]
arrayTemp [ 'c', 'd' ]
```

Whereas I'd like to have:

```
arrayModel [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
arrayTemp [ 'c', 'd' ]
```

I tried to used other methods.

Using `shift()` twice was also altering the model

`arrayTemp = array.slice(2)` was giving me back the opposite of what I wanted: `[ 'a', 'b']`

How should I proceed?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: I think you are correct @Andreas. The problem isn't that this lacks a solution but rather the person doesn't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

`Array#splice` mutates the original array. I would suggest you to use `Array#slice` and store the new array inside new variable.

```js
var arrayModel = ['a','b','c','d']

function dontAlterMyModel (arrayModel) {
  arrayTemp = arrayModel;
  var newArr = arrayTemp.slice(-2);
  console.log("arrayModel", arrayModel);
  console.log("arrayTemp", newArr);
}

dontAlterMyModel(arrayModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy original array by using object assign

```
  arrayTemp = Object.assign([], arrayModel).splice(0,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use minus numbers in slice

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var b = a.slice(-2);

console.log(a, b);
```